# in swift, how utf16 surrogate pair is represented in bit

Tags: swift, unicode, utf-8, bit, utf-16

I'm currently learning swift using the book swift programming language 3.1.

In the book, it states that swift's `String` and `Character` type is fully unicode compliant, with each character represented by a 21 bits unicode scalar value. Each character can be view via utf8, 16, 32.

I understand how utf8 and utf32 works in the byte and bit level, but I'm having trouble understanding how utf16 works in the bit level.

I know that for characters whose code point can be fit into 16 bits, utf16 simply represent the character as a 16 bit number. But for characters whose representation require more than 16 bits, two 16 bits block is used (called surrogate pair, I believe).

But how is the two 16 bits block is presented in bit level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ["Unicode Scalar Value"](http://unicode.org/glossary/#unicode_scalar_value) is

> Any Unicode code point except high-surrogate and low-surrogate code points. In other words, the ranges of integers 0 to D7FF<sub>16</sub> and E000<sub>16</sub> to 10FFFF<sub>16</sub> inclusive.

*Every* Unicode scalar value can be represented as a sequence of one or two UTF-16 code units, as described in the
[Unicode Standard](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/ch03.pdf):

> **D91 UTF-16 encoding form**
>
> The Unicode encoding form that assigns each Unicode scalar value in the ranges U+0000..U+D7FF and U+E000..U+FFFF to a single unsigned 16-bit code unit with the same numeric value as the Unicode scalar value, and that assigns each Unicode scalar value in the range U+10000..U+10FFFF to a surrogate pair, according to Table 3-5.
>
> ```
> Table 3-5. UTF-16 Bit Distribution
>
> Scalar Value              UTF-16
> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx          xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
> 000uuuuuxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  110110wwwwxxxxxx 110111xxxxxxxxxx
>
> Note: wwww = uuuuu - 1
> ```

There are 2<sup>20</sup> Unicode scalar values in the "Supplementary Planes" (U+10000..U+10FFFF), which means that 20 bits are sufficient to encode
all of them in a surrogate pair. Technically this is done by subtracting
0x010000 from the value before splitting it into two blocks of 10 bits.

Answer (score 1):

The utf16 range D800...DFFF is reserved. Values below and above that are simple 16 bit code points. Values D800..DBFF, minus D800, are the high 10 bits of 20-bit codes beyond FFFC. The next two bytes contain  the low 10 bits. Of course, endianness comes into the picture making us all wish we could just use utf8. Sigh.

Comment: thank you for the helpful comment. So I'm guessing that the max number of bit a utf16 character can have is 20 bits? 10 bits from the first block of 16 bits and another 10 bits from the second block of 16 bits? But I thought unicode scalar values are represented by 21 bit. So does it mean that something that can be represented by unicode scalar value (21 bits) can't be represented by utf16 (20 bits)?

Comment: @TonyStark: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF: 0x010000 is subtracted from the code point, leaving a 20-bit number in the range 0x000000..0x0FFFFF ....

Comment: @MartinR if utf16 is represented by a 20 bit number, and unicode scalar value (which is just code point for characters) is represented by a 21 bit number, does it mean some unicode scalar value can't be represented by utf16?

Comment: @TonyStark: Sorry, I don't get you. *All* valid Unicode code points from U+0 to U+10FFFF can be represented as 1 or 2 UTF-16 code units, and the Wikipedia article describes how it is done.

Comment: @TonyStark: Perhaps this quote from the Wikipedia article clears your doubts: Since the encoding of Supplementary Planes contain 10+10=20 significant bits, 2^20 code points can be handled, divided into 16 planes of 2^16 code points each. Including the separately handled Basic Multilingual Plane, there are in total 17 planes.

Comment: @MartinR thank you so so much for your help. You have helped me on a number of occasions in the past few months, I'm very grateful for all your help. So lucky to have  people like you on stackoverflow helping out people all around the world.